# TypeError while creating custom layer with tensorflow.map_fn

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to create a custom layer that calculates the forward kinematics for a robotic arm using 'DH parameters'. In my code, I am using the 6 joint angles as the input of the custom layer (Kinematics_Physics) and I am using `tensorflow.map_fn` to iteratively calculate the forward kinematics of each set of angles in the input. My goal is to set the 'DH parameters' as the trainable weights and train a model to optimize the 'DH parameters'. I am aware of the fact that this can be easily done using libraries like `scipy.optimize` or other optimization libraries, but I want to implement this in tensorflow so, I can add dense layers to learn the inverse kinematics of given custom layer. My code is as following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
from tensorflow import math as m
from tensorflow.keras import layers

class Kinematics_Physics(layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self,):
        super(Kinematics_Physics, self).__init__()
        # define initial variables
        self.TF_PI = tf.constant(3.1415926535897932, dtype =tf.float32)
        self.TF_180 = tf.constant(180.0, dtype =tf.float32)
        self.TINY_VALUE = tf.constant(1e-6, dtype =tf.float32)
        self.out_Pose=tf.Variable([0,0,0,0,0,0],  dtype =tf.float32, trainable = False)
        self.A_Deg = tf.Variable(0,dtype = tf.float32, trainable = False)
        self.B_Deg = tf.Variable(0,dtype = tf.float32, trainable = False)
        self.C_Deg = tf.Variable(0,dtype = tf.float32, trainable = False)
        self.sA = tf.Variable(0,dtype = tf.float32, trainable = False)
        self.cA = tf.Variable(0,dtype = tf.float32, trainable = False)
        self.b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((4,4),dtype = tf.float32),dtype = tf.float32, trainable = False)
        
        # initial dh parameters: 6 x 4 parameters for a robotic arm with 6 joints.
        dh = tf.constant([  [0 ,    180.,   -650.,  0.],
                            [270.,   90.,      0.,  0.],
                            [800.,    0.,      0.,  0.],
                            [140.,   90.,   -908.,  0.],
                            [0.,    -96.,      0.,  0.],
                            [0.,    -65.,   260.,   0.]] ,dtype = tf.float32)
        
        # convert to trainable weights?? for further optimization 
        self.dh = tf.Variable(initial_value=dh, trainable=True)

        # initialize a buffer to calculate the the modified angles
        self.dh_processed = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(self.dh.shape,dtype = tf.float32),dtype = tf.float32, trainable = False)
        # buffer for transformation matrix
        self.trans_matrix = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((4,4),dtype = tf.float32),  dtype =tf.float32, trainable = False)


    @tf.function
    def radians(self,a):
        return m.multiply(a,(tf.divide(self.TF_PI, self.TF_180 )))
    
    @tf.function
    def degrees(self,a):
        return m.multiply(a,(tf.divide(self.TF_180 , self.TF_PI)))
    
    @tf.function
    def joint_transform(self,input_values):
        '''input: format --> 1D array = [a, α, d, θ]'''
    
        a = input_values[0] # a
        alpha = self.radians(input_values[1]) #convert degrees to radians
        d = input_values[2] # d
        theta = self.radians(input_values[3]) #convert degrees to radians θ
        
        self.trans_matrix.assign(
                                [[      m.cos(theta),             -m.sin(theta),              0,                a],
                                [m.multiply(m.sin(theta),m.cos(alpha)),  m.multiply(m.cos(theta),m.cos(alpha)), -m.sin(alpha), m.multiply(-m.sin(alpha),d)],
                                [m.multiply(m.sin(theta),m.sin(alpha)),  m.multiply(m.cos(theta),m.sin(alpha)),  m.cos(alpha),  m.multiply(m.cos(alpha),d)],
                                [        0,                             0,                     0,            1        ]])
        return self.trans_matrix
    
    @tf.function
    def to_pose(self,T):
        # converts the transformation matrix to pose [x, y, z, alpha ]
        if(m.abs(T[1,2]) <= self.TINY_VALUE and m.abs(T[2,2]) <= self.TINY_VALUE): #% singular : B = +-90 (Gimbal Lock)
            self.C_Deg.assign(tf.constant(0, dtype =tf.float32))
            self.B_Deg.assign(self.degrees(m.atan2( T[0,2] , m.divide_no_nan(T[2,2], m.cos(self.C_Deg)) ))) #convert radians to degree
            self.A_Deg.assign(self.degrees(m.atan2( T[1,0] ,  m.divide_no_nan(T[1,1], m.cos(self.C_Deg)) ))) #convert radians to degree
        
        else:
            self.A_Deg.assign(self.degrees(m.atan2(-T[0,1] , T[0,0]))) #convert radians to degree
            self.sA.assign(m.sin(self.radians(self.A_Deg)))
            self.cA.assign(m.cos(self.radians(self.A_Deg)))
            self.B_Deg.assign(self.degrees(m.atan2(T[0,2] , m.multiply(self.cA,T[0,0]) - m.multiply(self.sA,T[0,1]))))#convert radians to degree
            self.C_Deg.assign(self.degrees(m.atan2(-T[1,2] , T[2,2]))) #convert radians to degree
        
        self.out_Pose.assign([ T[0,3], T[1,3], T[2,3],self.A_Deg, self.B_Deg , self.C_Deg])
        return self.out_Pose
    
    
    @tf.function
    def forward_kinematics(self, theta):
        
        # add the dh_theta to measured theta to get the final theta
        actual_theta = m.add(self.dh[:,3] ,theta)
        
        # create new dh_table with modified theta for forward kinematics calculation
        self.dh_processed[:,0].assign(self.dh[:,0])
        self.dh_processed[:,1].assign(self.dh[:,1])
        self.dh_processed[:,2].assign(self.dh[:,2])
        self.dh_processed[:,3].assign(actual_theta)
        b = tf.eye(4, dtype = tf.float32)
        for i in tf.range(6):
            b = (tf.linalg.matmul(b,self.joint_transform(self.dh_processed[i])))
        return self.to_pose(b)
      
    def __call__(self, inputs):
        return tf.map_fn(self.forward_kinematics, inputs, parallel_iterations=True, dtype=tf.float32)
    
    def get_config(self):
        config = super(Kinematics_Physics, self).get_config()
        return config
    
# Loss function
def Euclidean_distance(y,y_hat):
    #Euclidean distance between true and predicted values 
    # ony calculates errors for the distance between two points and ignores the orientation error.
    return tf.sqrt(tf.square(y[:,0]-y_hat[:,0])+tf.square(y[:,1]-y_hat[:,1])+tf.square(y[:,2]-y_hat[:,2]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create a list of six joint angles
    ang = tf.Variable([[20,10,20,10,10,20],[15,10,20,22,20,32]], dtype = tf.float32, trainable=False)
    # Call the Kinematics_physics layer
    fk = Kinematics_Physics()
    print("trainable weights: ", len(fk.trainable_weights))
    print("non-trainable weights: ", len(fk.non_trainable_weights))
    print("trainable_weights: ", fk.trainable_weights)
    print("forward kinematic transform: ", fk(ang[:10]))
    # Everything works up to this.

    # create a model using functional API
    in_= tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(6,))
    for_kin = Kinematics_Physics()(in_)
    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=in_, outputs=for_kin) 
    model.summary() 
    # Error: expected behavior => should create a model with 24 trainable parameters
    #        but the error happens in tf.map_fn of Kinematics_Physics().__call__ function
    
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=Euclidean_distance)
```

the program runs ok, when calculating the forward kinematics of given angles in 'ang' variable. but the model doesn't compile. the output of the program is as follow.

```
2020-10-22 16:04:42.554276: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2.2.0-rc3
2020-10-22 16:04:45.709129: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-10-22 16:04:45.935534: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 950M computeCapability: 5.0
coreClock: 0.928GHz coreCount: 5 deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 74.65GiB/s
2020-10-22 16:04:45.935854: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-10-22 16:04:45.945295: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll 
2020-10-22 16:04:45.958322: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll   
2020-10-22 16:04:45.964943: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll  
2020-10-22 16:04:45.972469: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-10-22 16:04:45.976487: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-10-22 16:04:45.989461: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-10-22 16:04:45.989837: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-10-22 16:04:45.990629: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2020-10-22 16:04:46.004638: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x1b9dbcd1da0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee 
that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-10-22 16:04:46.004803: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-10-22 16:04:46.005315: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 950M computeCapability: 5.0
coreClock: 0.928GHz coreCount: 5 deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 74.65GiB/s
2020-10-22 16:04:46.006569: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-10-22 16:04:46.007750: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-10-22 16:04:46.008228: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-10-22 16:04:46.008661: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-10-22 16:04:46.009383: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-10-22 16:04:46.009760: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-10-22 16:04:46.010063: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-10-22 16:04:46.010487: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-10-22 16:04:47.469597: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-10-22 16:04:47.470084: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1108]      0 
2020-10-22 16:04:47.470593: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 0:   N
2020-10-22 16:04:47.471191: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1247] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1368 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 950M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
2020-10-22 16:04:47.501674: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x1b9f8bff2f0 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee 
that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-10-22 16:04:47.502342: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce GTX 950M, Compute Capability 5.0
trainable weights:  1
non-trainable weights:  9
trainable_weights:  [<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(6, 4) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[   0.,  180., -650.,    0.],
       [ 270.,   90.,    0.,    0.],
       [ 800.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [ 140.,   90., -908.,    0.],
       [   0.,  -96.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,  -65.,  260.,    0.]], dtype=float32)>]
2020-10-22 16:04:49.335812: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
forward kinematic transform:  tf.Tensor(
[[ 548.9288   -118.251114 -527.5552     47.53804   -30.621014 -144.55815 ]
 [ 511.83533   -85.7232   -492.43372    49.052803  -46.484085 -145.28882 ]], shape=(2, 6), dtype=float32)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Desktop/physics-based Calibration/physics_layer.py", line 124, in <module>
    for_kin = Kinematics_Physics()(in_)
  File "c:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Desktop/physics-based Calibration/physics_layer.py", line 99, in __call__
    return tf.map_fn(self.forward_kinematics, inputs, parallel_iterations=True, dtype=tf.float32)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 574, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\map_fn.py", line 425, in map_fn_v2
    name=name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\map_fn.py", line 230, in map_fn
    for elem in elems_flat]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\map_fn.py", line 230, in <listcomp>
    for elem in elems_flat]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\tensor_array_ops.py", line 1082, in __init__
    name=name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\tensor_array_ops.py", line 717, in __init__
    self._tensor_array = [None for _ in range(size)]
TypeError: 'Tensor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Has anyone encountered similar problem before, Maybe I am doing something wrong while creating this model or custom layer. Any recommendations?

Tensorflow Version : 2.2.0-rc3,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming up with a solution was a bit of a journey.

### The problem: `map_fn` expect a Tensor, not a symbolic representation of a Tensor.

The problem that caused your error is a bit tricky to explain. But basically, when you are creating your keras model, the batch_size is unknown. It is the standard behaviour so you can feed different batch size to your model. However, the `map_fn` function expect to know the shape of the Tensor you are feeding it to create the execution graph. Which is not possible given that the batch size of your Input Layer is unknown! Using `map_fn` inside a `keras.Layer` seems difficult to do.

### The fix: using the indexing abilities of Tensorflow

The good thing is that we can skip the batch dimension by just referring to the part that interrest us : `inp[...,0]` gives us the first value of the last dimension of the `inp` Tensor without having to index on the batch_size.

The bad thing is that sometimes, we rely on the batch size, especially when we need some copies of the trainable weights for each input of the batch size. We can tell tensorflow to delay those calculation by using `tf.shape`

### Some comments

Some general comments about your code and the changes I made:

- you used a lot of `tf.Variable` as class attributes. Unless you need to keep a state between different batches, this is not needed. It makes the code harder to read because you need to use `assign` intead of `=`
- You used the `@tf.function` decorator on each method class. You need it only if you use operations like `for` loops that can only be eager executed and need to be converted before being executed in the Graph.
- You overrided `__call__` instead of `call`. Don't do that! The inherited [`__call__` function of `tf.keras.layers.Layer`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.1/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L875-L994) applies internal tensorflow logic to get certain guaranties. Redefine `call` instead.
- Don't use tf.Variable unless you need to track that variable. They are supposed to represent shared, persistent state your program manipulates. I suggest that you read the [Variable Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/variable).

### The Code

I was a bit liberal with the use of `[...,]` indexing.

```py
class KinematicsPhysics(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self,):
        super(KinematicsPhysics, self).__init__()
        # define initial variables
        self.TF_PI = tf.constant(3.1415926535897932, dtype=tf.float32)
        self.TF_180 = tf.constant(180.0, dtype=tf.float32)
        self.TINY_VALUE = tf.constant(1e-6, dtype=tf.float32)
        # initial dh parameters: 6 x 4 parameters for a robotic arm with 6 joints.
        self.INIT_DH = tf.constant(
            [
                [0, 180.0, -650.0, 0.0],
                [270.0, 90.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                [800.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                [140.0, 90.0, -908.0, 0.0],
                [0.0, -96.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                [0.0, -65.0, 260.0, 0.0],
            ],
            dtype=tf.float32,
        )
        self.dh = tf.Variable(initial_value=self.INIT_DH, trainable=True, dtype=tf.float32)


    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0],) + (6,)

    def radians(self, a):
        return m.multiply(a, (tf.divide(self.TF_PI, self.TF_180)))

    def degrees(self, a):
        return m.multiply(a, (tf.divide(self.TF_180, self.TF_PI)))

    def joint_transform(self, input_values):
        """input: format --> 1D array = [a, α, d, θ]"""
        a = input_values[..., 0]  # a
        alpha = self.radians(input_values[..., 1])  # convert degrees to radians
        d = input_values[..., 2]  # d
        theta = self.radians(input_values[..., 3])  # convert degrees to radians θ
        row1 = tf.stack(
            [m.cos(theta), -m.sin(theta), tf.zeros(tf.shape(theta)), a], axis=-1
        )
        row2 = tf.stack(
            [
                m.multiply(m.sin(theta), m.cos(alpha)),
                m.multiply(m.cos(theta), m.cos(alpha)),
                -m.sin(alpha),
                m.multiply(-m.sin(alpha), d),
            ],
            axis=-1,
        )
        row3 = tf.stack(
            [
                m.multiply(m.sin(theta), m.sin(alpha)),
                m.multiply(m.cos(theta), m.sin(alpha)),
                m.cos(alpha),
                m.multiply(m.cos(alpha), d),
            ],
            axis=-1,
        )
        row4 = tf.stack(
            [tf.zeros(tf.shape(a)), tf.zeros(tf.shape(a)), tf.zeros(tf.shape(a)), tf.ones(tf.shape(a))],
            axis=-1,
        )
        # final size (batch_size, 6, 4 , 4)
        return tf.stack([row1, row2, row3, row4], axis=-2)

    def to_pose(self, batch):
        def if_tiny_values(T):
            a = self.degrees(m.atan2(T[..., 1, 0], m.divide_no_nan(T[..., 1, 1], 1.0)))
            b = self.degrees(m.atan2(T[..., 0, 2], m.divide_no_nan(T[..., 2, 2], 1.0)))
            c = tf.zeros(tf.shape(a))
            return tf.stack([T[..., 0, 3], T[..., 1, 3], T[..., 2, 3], a, b, c], 1)

        def if_not_tiny(T):
            a = m.atan2(-T[..., 0, 1], T[..., 0, 0])
            b = self.degrees(
                m.atan2(
                    T[..., 0, 2],
                    m.multiply(m.cos(a), T[..., 0, 0])
                    - m.multiply(m.sin(a), T[..., 0, 1]),
                )
            )
            c = self.degrees(m.atan2(-T[..., 1, 2], T[..., 2, 2]))
            a = self.degrees(a)
            return tf.stack([T[..., 0, 3], T[..., 1, 3], T[..., 2, 3], a, b, c], 1)

        ret = []
        condition = tf.logical_and(
            m.abs(batch[..., 1, 2]) <= self.TINY_VALUE,
            m.abs(batch[..., 2, 2]) <= self.TINY_VALUE,
        )
        # tf.where does not have the broadcasting capabilities of its numpy equivalent
        # see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/15982
        condition = tf.expand_dims(condition, 1)
        # using tf.where instead of a if
        ret = tf.where(condition, if_tiny_values(batch), if_not_tiny(batch))

        return ret

    @tf.function
    def forward_kinematics(self, theta):
        # add the dh_theta to measured theta to get the final theta
        actual_theta = m.add(self.dh[:, 3], theta)
        # create new dh_table with modified theta for forward kinematics calculation
        # getting the first 3 column of dh
        dh_processed = tf.expand_dims(self.dh[...,:3], axis=0)
        dh_processed = tf.repeat(dh_processed, tf.shape(theta)[0], axis=0)
        # we add actual_theta as the last column. 
        dh_processed = tf.concat(
            [dh_processed, tf.expand_dims(actual_theta, -1)], 2
        )
        trans_matrix = self.joint_transform(dh_processed)
        # We create a Identity matrix for each input in the batch
        b = tf.repeat(tf.expand_dims(tf.eye(4, dtype=tf.float32),axis=0), tf.shape(theta)[0], axis=0)
        for i in tf.range(6):
            b = tf.linalg.matmul(b, trans_matrix[:, i, :, :])
        # b is shape (batch_size, 4, 4)
        return self.to_pose(b)

    def call(self, inputs):
        return self.forward_kinematics(inputs)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(KinematicsPhysics, self).get_config()
        return config
```

#### Running it with your example, we get :

```
>>> import numpy as np
... ang = np.array(
        [[20, 10, 20, 10, 10, 20], [15, 10, 20, 22, 20, 32]],
         dtype=np.float32
    )
... fk = KinematicsPhysics()
... fk(ang)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 6), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 548.9287  , -118.2511  , -527.5551  ,   47.538036,  -30.621014,      -144.55814 ],
       [ 511.83527 ,  -85.72318 , -492.43365 ,   49.052803,  -46.48408 ,       -145.28882 ]], dtype=float32)>
```

If you have some questions, don't hesitate to ask, I'll refine my answer.

Comment: This answer was very education. You have given me valuable insight on how to handle array operations in Tensor flow. Thank you very much for your time and effort. Really appreciate it.

Comment: While training the model an error happens, I think overall no 'for loops' are allowed during layer training?

Comment: @KumarS I assumed something wrong with keras and `tf.function`s. I've updated my answer. Out of curiosity, do you use `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` somewhere in your code?

Comment: thanks for the update. With @tf.function,  it works fine. And no I haven't use tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution() anywhere.